# javafx retain root while adding a secondary stage

Tags: button, javafx, menuitem, stage

I have a growing application with a menu bar with Home, Chapters, Calculator, Glossary, Help.  Everything is  working fine including the Chapters with 14 items.

Also the Calculator that is a source package.  It opens but I lose the stage.  I would like it  to open and able to be dragged around the screen.

This is the code I am using:

```
else if(e.getSource()==mbarcalculator){
        stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/javafxcalc/FXMLcalc.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        }
```

I have read a lot of posts but haven't found a simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of patience and perseverance I have a solution that works and one I can understand.

else if(e.getSource()==mbarcalculator){
    Stage secondaryStage = new Stage();
    Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/javafxcalc/FXMLcalc.fxml"));
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2);
    secondaryStage.setScene(scene2);
    secondaryStage.show();
    }

I took a small section of code from Jose Pereda's answer [Display two windows at the same time "on fullscreen" with JavaFx Scene Builder 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428142/display-two-windows-at-the-same-time-on-fullscreen-with-javafx-scene-builder-2)

I have tested it and it works nicely.