# What's causing this NullPointerException when I use stage.SetFullScreen(true) from the JavaFX library on a mac?

Tags: java, macos, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

Here's the code I'm using (copied mostly from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26431443/3217863)). It's a simple application that opens two stages, one on each of the two monitors connected to a mac mini running 10.9.1, using JDK 8u66.

```
    Screen primaryScreen = Screen.getPrimary();

    WebView  browser = new WebView();
    WebEngine engine = browser.getEngine();
    //String url = "http://menu.madebyxdlab.com/show.php?pageType=screen1";
    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    engine.load(url);
    System.out.println("First page loaded into WebEngine");

    WebView  browser2 = new WebView();
    WebEngine engine2 = browser2.getEngine();
    //String url2 = "http://menu.madebyxdlab.com/show.php?pageType=screen2";
    String url2= "http://www.yahoo.com";
    engine2.load(url2);
    System.out.println("Second page loaded into WebEngine");

    //Pane pane = new Pane(browser);

    Scene scene = new Scene(browser);


    Rectangle2D bounds = primaryScreen.getBounds();
    primaryStage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
    primaryStage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
    primaryStage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
    primaryStage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    System.out.println("First Screen Set");


    //       look for a second screen
    Screen.getScreens().stream()
    .filter(s->!s.equals(primaryScreen))
    .findFirst().ifPresent(s->secondaryScreen = s);

    if(secondaryScreen!=null){
        System.out.println("Second Screen detected");
        Stage secondaryStage = new Stage();
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(browser2);
        secondaryStage.setScene(scene2);
        Rectangle2D bounds2 = secondaryScreen.getBounds();
        secondaryStage.setX(bounds2.getMinX());
        secondaryStage.setY(bounds2.getMinY());
        secondaryStage.setWidth(bounds2.getWidth());
        secondaryStage.setHeight(bounds2.getHeight());
        secondaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        secondaryStage.show();  
        System.out.println("Second Screen Set");
    }
```

If `primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);` is commented out, it works fine, but if it's active, the system throws the following NPE:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.webkit.theme.ScrollBarThemeImpl.getThumb(ScrollBarThemeImpl.java:409)
at com.sun.javafx.webkit.theme.ScrollBarThemeImpl.thumbPosition(ScrollBarThemeImpl.java:293)
at com.sun.javafx.webkit.theme.ScrollBarThemeImpl.getThumbPosition(ScrollBarThemeImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.webkit.Timer.twkFireTimerEvent(Native Method)
at com.sun.webkit.Timer.fireTimerEvent(Timer.java:83)
at com.sun.webkit.Timer.notifyTick(Timer.java:64)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PulseTimer.lambda$static$45(WebEngine.java:1201)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(MacApplication.java:109)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:511)
at com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView._enterFullscreen(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.enterFullscreen(View.java:784)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.applyFullScreen(WindowStage.java:630)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.setFullScreen(WindowStage.java:720)
at javafx.stage.Stage.impl_visibleChanged(Stage.java:1189)
at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Window.java:895)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:922)
at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:937)
at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:259)
at fullScreenHandler.fullScreenCreator.start(fullScreenCreator.java:63)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

I understand that I can not run both stages fullscreen, but I'm hoping to run the first screen in full screen at least and then adjust the second. The URL's are placeholders since they deployment pages are display only, with no interactions.

Comment: primaryStage is not initialized when you call that set-method.

Comment: primaryStage comes from `public void start(Stage primaryStage)` which is the line right before my code. I did not think it needed to be initialised. However, I've added a `primaryStage = new Stage();` right at the start and I'm still seeing the same issue.

Comment: In that case, check what that setter does, then it's a variable in primaryStage, which you are trying to set, that is not initialized.

Comment: So the setter changes `primaryStage.fullscreen.value` to `true`. This is both expected and wanted behavior. Stepping through the code, this line does not actually throw the Exception. The line two down from it does (`primaryStage.show();`). However, commenting out the `setFullScreen(true)` line still makes `show()` work properly.

Comment: Hmm. During some update (I *think* of JavaFX 2.2), JavaFX switched from a custom full-screen implementation on the Mac to using the native implementation. (Prior versions of JavaFX had supported earlier OS X versions that didn't have user-level full-screen functionality included.) I know early versions of the native full screen implementation with two monitors didn't allow any interaction with the secondary monitor at all, but that changed in a subsequent OS X release. So it's not a big surprise to me that your code unveils a bug, as the JavaFX full screen support was likely targetted...

Comment: ... at a OS X version that wouldn't have supported this at all. You should file this as a bug, and I think as a workaround just let both stages use the maximum available bounds on each screen, instead of using full screen mode (if you can).

Comment: I'm settling for that workaround. Updated to OSX 10.11.1 which has an "auto hide menu bar" option that applies system wide, along with an already hidden dock. And I'm giving each stage maximum bounds. So it'll suffice for now.